# Can't Delete Record 2sxc Error: No parent ID listed and item is Brand New

Tags: 2sxc

Getting this error on any piece of content we try and delete across entire site. So not isolated to a certain entity. We add even a brand new 2sxc content module, add a new item and then try and delete and get this as the error:

2sxc version 14.12.3
DNN 9.10.2

{Message: "Bad Request", ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException",…}
ExceptionMessage
:
"Can't delete Item 22002. It is used by others. Found 1 relationships where this is a child - the parents are: 2SexyContent-ContentGroup."
ExceptionType
:
"System.InvalidOperationException"
Message
:
"Bad Request"

Expected record to be permanently deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as an entity is in use, this warning appears to protect users from "shooting themselves in the foot".

If you delete it from the Admin-UI, you should also get a question to force delete (because Admins should know what they are doing).

You are probably trying to delete it from the toolbar - which usually means that the item is already in use (as it was added to the page).